# Why boost log not found?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake, travis-ci

I successfully build my project on locale machine, but when i upload my build in Travis i see this:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182
>   (message):
>
> Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.46.1
>
> Boost include path: /usr/include
>
> Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
>
> **boost_log**
>
> Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You
>   may
>
> need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively,
>   set
>
> BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or
>   BOOST_ROOT
>
> to the location of Boost.
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I many time search this error in google, but i not found answer. My CMakeList file this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Recast-server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES
        "src/*.h"
        "src/*.c"
        "src/*.cpp")

include_directories(src/headers/)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)

find_package(Boost 1.46 COMPONENTS  system
                                    thread
                                    log
                                    log_setup
                                    program_options
                                    filesystem
             REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Recast-server ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Recast-server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Recast-server ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

You can ask(or try commit) also in this PullRequest: https://github.com/bender-wardrobe/Recast/pull/15

Big Thanks for your answer <3

Comment: You can see travis.yml file this: https://github.com/bender-wardrobe/Recast/blob/7593e3f07e0a2b0ea8db5b98b5aa4126c8d131cc/.travis.yml

Comment: Wow, that's an *old* boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly Boost.Log was only added in later versions of Boost.

For earlier versions of Boost you can use the standalone Boost.Log from http://boost-log.sf.net

**edit**

You set the version 1.46 in your CMakeLists.txt. Maybe try a later version. Don't know about Travis.

Comment: Ok... How i can install new version Boost with travis? Any PPA?

Comment: But on local machine is compiling.

Comment: On travis Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is rather old, so I  guess the by default installed Boost is the very old  1.46.

Comment: You could install a newer boost version manually and not use the version provided by package manager.

Comment: i try compile from source Boost, but... It very long time :(